# linq join with an or condition

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

I'm building a linq query thus:

```
From G In Games _
            Where G.Field(Of Integer)("SystemID") = System _
            Join F In Files On _
            F.Field(Of String("Name") Equals G.Field(Of String)("PrimaryFilename") _
            Select New With {
                .gid = G.Field(Of Integer)("ID"),
                .ggamename = G.Field(Of String)("GameName")}
```

I'm wanting the join to happen where it equals one value OR another. Something like this (which naturally doesn't work):

```
From G In Games _
            Where G.Field(Of Integer)("SystemID") = System _
            Join F In Files On _
            F.Field(Of String("Name") Equals G.Field(Of String)("PrimaryFilename") OR G.Field(Of String)("SafeFilename") _
            Select New With {
                .gid = G.Field(Of Integer)("ID"),
                .ggamename = G.Field(Of String)("GameName")}
```

How would I go about this?

---

UPDATE

Helpful suggestion below, but a cross-join turned out to be too expensive + slow. I also tried the method below:

```
Dim query1 = _
            From G In Games _
            Where G.Field(Of Integer)("SystemID") = System _
            Join F In Files On _
            G.Field(Of String)("PrimaryFilename") Equals F.Field(Of String)("Name") _
            Select New With {
                .gid = G.Field(Of Integer)("ID"),
                .ggamename = G.Field(Of String)("GameName"),
                .gprimaryfilename = G.Field(Of String)("PrimaryFilename"),
                .gsafegamename = G.Field(Of String)("SafeGameName")}

dim  query2 = _
           From G In Games _
           Where G.Field(Of Integer)("SystemID") = System _
           Join F In Files On _
           G.Field(Of String)("SafeGameName") Equals F.Field(Of String)("Name") _
            Select New With {
            .gid = G.Field(Of Integer)("ID"),
            .ggamename = G.Field(Of String)("GameName"),
            .gprimaryfilename = G.Field(Of String)("PrimaryFilename"),
            .gsafegamename = G.Field(Of String)("SafeGameName")}

Dim query = query1.Union(query2)
```

But this produced some bizarre results (wrong matches) - feeling a bit out of my depth. Any other suggestions about how to achieve a simple "or" match?

Answer (score 1):

Linq only supports equi-joins.  You can try doing a "cross-join" and putting the condition in your `where` clause:

```
From G In Games _
    Where G.Field(Of Integer)("SystemID") = System _
    From F In Files _
    Where (F.Field(Of String("Name") = G.Field(Of String)("PrimaryFilename")) _
       Or (F.Field(Of String("Name") = G.Field(Of String)("SafeFilename")) _
    Select New With {
        .gid = G.Field(Of Integer)("ID"),
        .ggamename = G.Field(Of String)("GameName")}
```

Comment: Thanks, man. However - this method seems to run incredibly slowly - read somewhere that cross-joins are very expensive. I've updated OP to include another approach I tried. Any quicker methods?